# Install Magento 2.1 on AWS?

Tags: magento-2.1, aws

Currently the version supported "natively" by AWS Quick Start Reference Deployment is the 1.9.2:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/magento/overview.html

Is there any documentation on deploying (and upgrading afterwards) the latest Magento 2.1 on it?

Thank you

Comment: There is no direct upgrade path from Magento 1.x to 2.x, not sure if you know that already.

Comment: The plan is to use 2.1 from the start, the upgrade I'm talking about is for future 2.1 minor versions (2.1.4, 2.1.5...)

Answer (score 0):

You will find the latest AMI from Bitnami here

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NNZTA6Y/ref=mkt_ste_catgtm_devlp

You can use this version to install via an EC2 instance. I would recommend starting a production instance from a blank AMI and installing the recommended items as listed in DevDocs

After you have installed and have Magento running you can easily upgrade it in the future